# System error/ThrowBackwardCompatibleException in FullTextSqlQuery for many hits

Tags: 2010, search

We are using SharePoint Search (not FAST) in SharePoint 2010 to execute a FullTextSqlQuery. It works fine, but often (not Always) it gives errors for search strings (FREETEXT(*, '')) that gives many hits (like "a*"), but recently also for Words like "pdf"

We have set Rowlimit to 500 rows.

Is this a timeout problem? Ive read that default is 10s, and it takes way shorter time to get this error

(I only get this errors on our production, so notso much time to trial and error) (this is not an AllNoiseException)

Here is the Exception and stack trace from searching for "pdf"

```
FullTextSearchHelper, Error at FullTextSearch Scope="<MyScope>", SearchString="pdf",  System error.   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ThrowBackwardCompatibleException(FaultException`1 ex)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.Execute()
```